# VBA - Excel Class Function - Logic

Tags: vba, excel, class

Using VBA to sort through employee course records. I have an Employee class and am trying to identify people individuals who satisfy the condition "has this but not that." I have stepped through the code and all works just fine, except for my condition testing in `BlsHasIssue()`. Pertinent code:

```
'''''''''''''
'clsEmployee'
'''''''''''''
Option Explicit

Private empID As String
Private name As String
Private hasBLSComp As Boolean
Private hasBLSAssignment As Boolean

Public Property Let id(value As String)
    empID = value
End Property

Property Get id() As String
    id = empID
End Property

Public Property Let setName(value As String)
    name = value
End Property

Public Property Get getName() As String
    getName = name
End Property

Public Sub addResusRecord(value As String)  'accepts name of course
    Select Case value
        Case "BLS Assignment":
            hasBLSAssignment = True
        Case "BLS Competency":
            hasBLSComp = True
    End Select
End Sub

Public Function BlsHasIssue() As Boolean
    If hasBLSComp And Not hasBLSAssignment Then
        BlsHasIssue = True
    Else
        BlsHasIssue = False
    End If
End Function

''''''''
'Module'
''''''''
Option Explicit

Const STUDENT_NAME_COL As Integer = 3
Const USER_ID_COL As Integer = 4
Const COURSE_NAME_COL As Integer = 5

Public Function Contains(col As Collection, key As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim obj As Variant
    On Error GoTo err
    Contains = True
    IsObject (col(key))
    Exit Function
err:
    Contains = False
End Function

    Sub ResusCardAudit()

    Dim row As Long
    Dim currEmpID As String
    Dim employees As New Collection
    Dim emp As Object

    For row = 2 To 5 'change to be last row of data
        'Check to see if user exists in collection
        currEmpID = Cells(row, USER_ID_COL).value

        If Not Contains(employees, currEmpID) Then
            'create User and add it to collection
            Set emp = New clsEmployee
            emp.id = currEmpID
            emp.setName = Cells(row, STUDENT_NAME_COL)
            emp.addResusRecord Cells(row, COURSE_NAME_COL)
            employees.Add emp, currEmpID
        Else
            employees.Item(currEmpID).addResusRecord Cells(row, COURSE_NAME_COL)
        End If

    Next row

    'cycle through all employees and determine if any have a comp but not an assignment
    Set emp = New clsEmployee
    row = 2
    For Each emp In employees
        If emp.BlsHasIssue Then

            row = row + 1
        End If
    Next emp

    'if they do, add their details to a new sheet named "Results"


End Sub
```

I have left out the code which properly sets `hasBLSComp` and `hasBLSAssignment.` The issue seems to be a logic error when testing `emp.BlsHasIssue`. The test which has brought me here is when `hasBLSComp` is True and `hasBLSAssignment` is False -> `BlsHasIssue()` results in False.

Note: It is acceptable for `hasBLSAssignment` to be True and `hasBLSComp` to be False.

Thoughts?

Comment: Are you sure the error is in your `BlsHasIssue` function?  Your `ResusCardAudit` subroutine isn't doing anything at the moment (iterating through an empty collection is a bit pointless) so perhaps you only **think** your function isn't working because it has never been called.  If you **do** have something in that collection, it might be an idea to show us how it is being set up.  (Not necessarily all of the code, but enough that we can replicate the issue.)

Comment: The logic you show here is good - it worked for me when I tried it.  So the issue must be someplace else.

Comment: I will add more code

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and guess that the **last** employee you added to the `employees` collection would be expected to give a `False` result.  (I'm guessing you have not been creating new `clsEmployee` objects for each entry in the collection, and thus been changing the existing one and using it for all entries.)  Nope - I was wrong.

Comment: My Locals window shows the collection containing two employees as expected. One has True True condition and the other has True False. Also, @YowE3K, you are so fast in your responses and have been very helpful to me over time here. Thanks!

Comment: I jumped the gun on my guess - you are correctly creating New objects each time.  I'll try and replicate the issue.

Comment: Added consts to my module code above.

Comment: Unrelated, but `BlsHasIssue` could be implemented as a simple `BlsHasissue = hasBLSComp And Not hasBLSAssignment` one-liner.

Comment: I just tested the code with four students, one having just "BLS Competency", one having just "BLS Assignment", one having both, and one having neither.  The one having just "BLS Competency" correctly returned a `BLSHasissue` of `True`.

Comment: Probably not very helpful but I can't replicate your problem - results as @YowE3K. (Btw is Contains a function?)

Comment: @SJR I was wondering the same thing - I ended up coding `Function Contains(c As Collection, k As String) As Boolean` `On Error Resume Next` `Contains = Not c(k) Is Nothing` `On Error GoTo 0` `End Function` which seemed to do what I assume it is trying to do.

Comment: Added Contains() just in case. I receive no errors, all data appears correct when I step through the program, but yet incorrect results.

Comment: Basically Assignment equates to BlsHasIssue=False and Competency equates to BlsHasIssue=True? I would double-check @YowE3K's point about the exact strings.

Comment: Can you put a breakpoint on the `BlsHasIssue = False` line and, when it reaches it for the record you think it shouldn't reach it for, verify that `hasBLSComp` is definitely `True` and that `hasBLSAssignment` is definitely `False`.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the all of the help. It was an **error in my test case**--I set the test as the inverse of what I thought I had. This has helped me realize the importance of (valid) multiple test cases before determining something is a problem.

Based on the responses to my question: I will stop hiding the simple logic that tests for an issue in the records and bring it to the module level. I believe this will help me avoid issues moving forward as the code expands.